# How define new 'GeoExt.panel.Map' with OpenLayers-3.6.0 and Extjs-6.0?

Tags: openlayers, geoext, ext-js, model-view-viewmodel

I'm using `OpenLayrs-3.6.0` and `Extjs-6.0`. I want to define GeoMap Panel class like [this](http://geoext.github.io/geoext2/docs/#!/api/GeoExt.panel.Map). In other words, I want to rewrite `GeoExt.panel.Map` in `geoExt-2` library.
for this I define a class as follow:

```
Ext.define('MyApp2.view.geo.Map', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires: [
    ],
    xtype: 'geoMap',
    layout: 'fit',
    map: null,
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        var html = '<div id="myId" class="MyId" ></div>';


        mm = me.map;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        Ext.apply(me, {html: html});

        me.map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'myId',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: "Global Imagery",
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/world/wms?service=WMS',
                        params: {LAYERS: 'world:worldRaster', VERSION: '1.1.1'}
                    })
                }),
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                center: [35, 41],
                zoom: 4
            })
        });
    },
});
```

The strategy is that create a panel and set its html with: `<div id="map" class="map"></div>`. I then create a `ol.map` instance and set its target with: "**map**"(the "id" of div in html panel).

This solution does not work, **How do I do**?

or

**Someone knows a better solution?**

Comment: geoext only works with extjs 4. Except if you are doing something completely custom it wont work.

Comment: I'm developing **my**`GeoExt.panel.Map`. I don't use `GeoExt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use OpenLayers 3 with Ext JS 6 you should have a look at https://github.com/KaiVolland/geoext3. It will be merged into https://github.com/geoext/geoext3 in about two weeks.

Even if you don't want to use GeoExt 3 itself, you could use some code of the `GeoExt.panel.Map` and `GeoExt.panel.MapController`.

The most interesting part might be the onResize method in the controller:

```
onResize: function(){
    // Get the corresponding view of the controller (the mapPanel).
    var mapPanel = this.getView();
    if(!mapPanel.mapRendered){
        mapPanel.getMap().setTarget(mapPanel.getTargetEl().dom);
        mapPanel.mapRendered = true;
    } else {
        mapPanel.getMap().updateSize();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes thanks a lot. An irrelevant question: You're also active in the project OpenLayers 3? When 3D section is completed?

Comment: I'm not really active in OpenLayers 3 so i don't know much about the 3D-Section.
But  you can find releases of the cesium integration library here: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3-cesium/releases/

Answer (score 2):

in Ext 4.2 I am using Container inside of Panel:
added in initComponent:

> ```
>     th.items = [
>         Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
>             initComponent: function () {
>                 var me = this;
>                 th.mapContainerId = me.id;
> ```

```
                me.on("boxready", function () {
                    th.initMap();
                });

                me.on("resize", function () {
                    if (th.mapInst) {
                        th.mapInst.updateSize();
                    }
                });

                me.callParent(arguments);
            }
        })
    ];
```

`th` is Panel, and `me` is Container. It prefered to initialize the map instanse `once` when Container is `ready` and `update map size` when Outer Container's `size changed`